# What is the technical parameter details of Genus Bidirectional microcontroller based ABT Energy meter ( 3Ph 4 wire)? Please someone help me out

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, energy, energy-transmission, metering

[image]I am unable to figure out the different parameters of Genus Bidirectional ABT Energy meter. I am working for the installation of SEM meters for the feeders in substation. I know about the energy quadrants and Cumulative import or export KVAh,KWh,TODs,Max demand etc. but can't figure out the other parameters.Please someone who has experience in energy meter reading help me out.